# Couldn't mount nfs shares with more than four files

Tags: linux, nfs, openstack

I am trying to mount a remote NFS share on open-stack cloud instance. I am able to mount the NFS share with fewer than five files , but if the number and size of files increase , then it fails to mount , the process gets stuck. The NFS share mounts successfully everywhere else. What could be the possible problem?

Comment: To clarify: 

You are able to *mount* the file system, but when you open/access more than 5 files it won't let you do any more operations? 

Because the other reading of your question: That a NFS server fails to mount if there are more than 5 files on it--simply doesn't make sense. 

Is it possible for you to share relevant lines from /etc/exports on the NFS server, and the mount command you use?

Comment: Yes , it fails to mount large shares , the mount operation get stuck. for small shares , the mount succeeds.

Comment: Wait. 

"Large" and "Small". What are the PHYSICAL sizes of the NFS volumes that fail, and the size of those that succeed? 

Also what is the OS, kernel version and 32 bit v.s. 64 bit?

Comment: Got it solved , it was slow network issue